# Return a modified new object from a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

what is the best practice to modify and return a new object from a function?

I wrote the following function :

```
export const addItemToCart = (currentCart, item) => {
  const { name, ...otherProps } = item;

  //if item exist in the cart
  if (currentCart[name]) {
    currentCart[name]["quantity"]++;
    return currentCart;
  } 
  //if the item does not exist
  else
  {
    currentCart[name] = { ...otherProps };
    currentCart[name]["quantity"] = 1;
    return currentCart;
  }

// the function must return a new modified object on each call
};
```

Obviously, the hard-coded property "quantity", and the return statements can definitely be improved.

how can I improve this function to be more readable?

Comment: looks like something more for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More "readable" is very opinion-based, either way, you can try something like this:

```js
const currentCart = {
  hello: {
    quantity: 1
  }
};

const addItemToCart = (currentCart, item) => {
  const { name } = item;

  // Short circuit + return the last value
  const quantityPrev = currentCart[name] && currentCart[name].quantity;

  // Or operator on boolean expression
  const quantity = 1 + (quantityPrev || 0);

  // Destructing for shallow copy, dynamic key assign
  return { ...currentCart, [name]: { quantity } };
};

console.log(addItemToCart(currentCart, { name: 'hello' }));
console.log(addItemToCart(currentCart, { name: 'blazer' }));
```